# How to color rows when using makecell?

Tags: tables, color, makecell

I'd like to color the rows of a table to make it easy readable. Some cells have multiple lines, so I use the makecell package, and planned to use the xcolor for coloring, but they are clashing. Sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bpchem}

\begin{document}
    %\rowcolors[1]{gray!25}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \BPChem{H\_2O}&\BPChem{H\_3N}&\BPChem{H\_4C}\\
        \makecell{\BPChem{H\_2O\_2}\\unstable}&\BPChem{H\_4N\_2}&\BPChem{H\_6C\_2}\\
        not exists&\makecell{\BPChem{H\_5N\_3}\\unstable}&\BPChem{H\_8C\_3}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\rowcolors` command needs 3 mandatory arguments. As I don't have  `bpchem` installed,
I loaded `chemformula`, which anyway has a simpler syntax for compounds. I took the liberty to change the shade of grey for a nicer one, and added some vertical padding at the top of rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
 \rowcolors{1}{Lavender!80!gray}{white}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \ch{H2O}&\ch{H3N}&\ch{H4C}\\
        \makecell[t]{\ch{H2O2}\\unstable}&\ch{H4N2}&\ch{H6C2}\\
        not exists&\makecell[t]{\ch{H5N3}\\unstable}&\ch{H8C3}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't take to the '\rowcolors' error, because any sequence brings option clash.

Comment: Ooops, your sample worked for me too... Mine too... Then I found that the xcolor clashes not with makecell, but  the beamer class. Thanks for the help and sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: It's a classical problem: you want to load a package with some options, and another package already loads it with other (non incompatible) options. Two  solutions: either load your options via the document class, or add to the preamble `\PassOptionsToPackage{options list}{packagename}`.

Comment: For `beamer`, one should add `xcolor=table` to the class options.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (you won't see any white lines in the colored panels).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
\CodeBefore
\rowcolors{1}{gray!15}{}
\Body
   \ch{H2O}&\ch{H3N}&\ch{H4C}\\
   \Block[t]{}{\ch{H2O2}\\unstable}&\ch{H4N2}&\ch{H6C2}\\
   not exists&\Block[t]{}{\ch{H5N3}\\unstable}&\ch{H8C3}\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]